# Postgres unique constraint across two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint, unique-index

Here's my current database structure:

```
Col1   Col2
 1    abc123
 1    abc123
 1    def321
 2    xyz789
 2    xyz789
```

I'd like to ensure that any entry in `Col2` is only used for the same entry in `Col1`. For example, the database would let you add this row:

```
Col1   Col2
 2    lmn456
```

But not this one:

```
Col1   Col2
 2    abc123
```

Is there a way to enforce this with a unique index? Normally, the unique enforces that the specific combination is unique for the entire table (i.e. `(1,abc123)` shows up no more than once).

I can't move `Col2` to a different table and use a join because I need to support multiple values of `Col2` for each entry in `Col1` - it's not 1-to-1.

Comment: Why would you want/need to keep duplicates? Gordon wasn't totally wrong when he said you probably have a modeling issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical case for using an [exclude constraint.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE)

The constraint will use btree operators `<>` and `=`, hence you have to install [btree_gist extension.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html)

```
create extension if not exists btree_gist;

create table my_table(
    col1 int, 
    col2 text,
    exclude using gist (col1 with <>, col2 with =)
);
```

Test:

```
insert into my_table values
    (1, 'abc123'),
    (1, 'abc123'),
    (1, 'def321'),
    (2, 'xyz789'),
    (2, 'xyz789')
returning *;

 col1 |  col2  
------+--------
    1 | abc123
    1 | abc123
    1 | def321
    2 | xyz789
    2 | xyz789
(5 rows)    

insert into my_table 
values (2, 'abc123');

ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "my_table_col1_col2_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (col1, col2)=(2, abc123) conflicts with existing key (col1, col2)=(1, abc123).
```

Comment: Thanks. The "cage at a zoo" example in that doc is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

No.  You have the wrong data structure.

You should be storing `col2` in a separate table one row per `col1` and `col2`.  Then you can lookup the value using a `join`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! This won't work because I want to have multiple values of `Col2` for the same value in `Col1`. I'll update the example to make this clear.

Comment: @gwintrob . . . I don't understand your comment at all.  These would just be stored in different rows.

Comment: Unrelated comment. It's pretty cool that StackOverflow brings together 2 Gordons who both graduated from MIT :)

Can you explain more about how the join would work? I thought you were suggesting that there would be unique constraint on `col2` in the separate table.